# Same resource for multiple locales

Tags: android, android-resources

I've a pretty large `raw` resource. I's a few megs voiceover. I have it in English (`raw`) and Czech (`raw-cs`) languages. But in Czech Republic, there is a also a lot of Slovaks (`raw-sk`), so it would make sense to also give Slovaks Czech voiceover. But I thinks it's a dumb idea to have copy of the same file in APK. So, is there a way to simply have same resource for multiple locales?